# how to select best fit continuous distribution from two Goodness-to-fit tests?

Tags: python, scipy, statistics, distribution, statistical-test

I looked into the question [Best fit Distribution plots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620471/fitting-empirical-distribution-to-theoretical-ones-with-scipy-python?noredirect=1&lq=1) and found out that answers submitted were using the Kolmogorov-Smirnov Test to find the best fit distribution. I also found out that there is an Anderson-Darling test that is also used to get the best fit distribution. So, I have a few questions:

**Question 1:**

If I have data and pass it through the NumPy histogram, what parameters should I use and what output should I input into the distribution?

```
def get_hist(data, data_size):
#### General code:
bins_formulas = ['auto', 'fd', 'scott', 'rice', 'sturges', 'doane', 'sqrt']
# bins = np.histogram_bin_edges(a=data, bins='scott')
# bins = np.histogram_bin_edges(a=data, bins='auto')
bins = np.histogram_bin_edges(a=data, bins='fd')
# print('Bin value = ', bins)

# Obtaining the histogram of data:
# Hist, bin_edges = histogram(a=data, bins=bins, range=np.linspace(start=np.min(data),end=np.max(data),size=data_size), density=True)
# Hist, bin_edges = histogram(a=data, range=np.linspace(np.min(data), np.max(data), data_size), density=True)
# Hist, bin_edges = histogram(a=data, bins=bins, density=True)
# Hist, bin_edges = histogram(a=data, bins=bins, range=(min(data), max(data)), normed=True, density=True)
# Hist, bin_edges = histogram(a=data, density=True)
Hist, bin_edges = histogram(a=data, range=(min(data), max(data)), density=True)
return Hist
```

**Question 2:**

If I want to combine both tests, how can I do that? what parameters are the best to use for finding the best fit distribution? Here is my attempt in combining both tests.

```
from statsmodels.stats.diagnostic import anderson_statistic as adtest
def get_best_distribution(data):
    dist_names = ['alpha', 'anglit', 'arcsine', 'beta', 'betaprime', 'bradford', 'burr', 'cauchy', 'chi', 'chi2', 'cosine', 'dgamma', 'dweibull', 'erlang', 'expon', 'exponweib', 'exponpow', 'f', 'fatiguelife', 'fisk', 'foldcauchy', 'foldnorm', 'frechet_r', 'frechet_l', 'genlogistic', 'genpareto', 'genexpon', 'genextreme', 'gausshyper', 'gamma', 'gengamma', 'genhalflogistic', 'gilbrat',  'gompertz', 'gumbel_r', 'gumbel_l', 'halfcauchy', 'halflogistic', 'halfnorm', 'hypsecant', 'invgamma', 'invgauss', 'invweibull', 'johnsonsb', 'johnsonsu', 'ksone', 'kstwobign', 'laplace', 'logistic', 'loggamma', 'loglaplace', 'lognorm', 'lomax', 'maxwell', 'mielke', 'moyal', 'nakagami', 'ncx2', 'ncf', 'nct', 'norm', 'pareto', 'pearson3', 'powerlaw', 'powerlognorm', 'powernorm', 'rdist', 'reciprocal', 'rayleigh', 'rice', 'recipinvgauss', 'semicircular', 't', 'triang', 'truncexpon', 'truncnorm', 'tukeylambda', 'uniform', 'vonmises', 'wald', 'weibull_min', 'weibull_max', 'wrapcauchy']
    dist_ks_results = []
    dist_ad_results = []
    params = {}
    for dist_name in dist_names:
        dist = getattr(st, dist_name)
        param = dist.fit(data)
        params[dist_name] = param

        # Applying the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test
        D_ks, p_ks = st.kstest(data, dist_name, args=param)
        print("Kolmogorov-Smirnov test Statistics value for " + dist_name + " = " + str(D_ks))
        # print("p value for " + dist_name + " = " + str(p_ks))
        dist_ks_results.append((dist_name, p_ks))

        # Applying the Anderson-Darling test:
        D_ad = adtest(x=data, dist=dist, fit=False, params=param)
        print("Anderson-Darling test Statistics value for " + dist_name + " = " + str(D_ad))
        dist_ad_results.append((dist_name, D_ad))

        print(dist_ks_results)
        print(dist_ad_results)

        for D in range (len(dist_ks_results)):
           KS_D = dist_ks_results[D][1]
           AD_D = dist_ad_results[D][1]
           if KS_D < 0.25 and AD_D < 0.05:
                best_ks_D = KS_D
                best_ad_D = AD_D
                if dist_ks_results[D][1] == best_ks_D:
                   best_ks_dist = dist_ks_results[D][0]
                if dist_ad_results[D][1] == best_ad_D:
                   best_ad_dist = dist_ad_results[D][0]

            print(best_ks_D)
            print(best_ad_D)
            print(best_ks_dist)
            print(best_ad_dist)

            print('\n################################ Kolmogorov-Smirnov test parameters #####################################')
            print("Best fitting distribution (KS test): " + str(best_ks_dist))
            print("Best test Statistics value (KS test): " + str(best_ks_D))
            print("Parameters for the best fit (KS test): " + str(params[best_ks_dist])
            print('################################################################################\n')
            print('################################ Anderson-Darling test parameters #########################################')
            print("Best fitting distribution (AD test): " + str(best_ad_dist))
            print("Best test Statistics value (AD test): " + str(best_ad_D))
            print("Parameters for the best fit (AD test): " + str(params[best_ad_dist]))
            print('################################################################################\n')
```

**Question 3:**

How can I obtain the p-value for the Anderson-Darling test?

**Question 4:**

Say that I managed to get the best fit distribution, how is it possible to rank the distributions based on the tests? like the photo below.

[Goodness-to-fit tests with ranking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y00S8.png)

***Edit 1***

I am not sure but is the normal_ad from statsmodel general Anderson-Darling test for any continuous probability distribution? if it is, I would like to select the distribution that is common for both tests, If I follow the same steps in question 1 will it be the right approach? Also, say if I want to find the highest p-value and is common in both tests, how can I extract the common distribution name with the p-values?

```
def get_best_distribution(data):
dist_names = ['beta', 'bradford', 'burr', 'cauchy', 'chi', 'chi2', 'erlang', 'expon', 'f', 'fatiguelife', 'fisk', 'gamma', 'genlogistic', 'genpareto', 'invgauss', 'johnsonsb', 'johnsonsu', 'laplace', 'logistic', 'loggamma', 'loglaplace', 'lognorm', 'maxwell', 'mielke', 'norm', 'pareto', 'reciprocal', 'rayleigh', 't', 'triang', 'uniform', 'weibull_min', 'weibull_max']
dist_ks_results = []
dist_ad_results = []
params = {}
for dist_name in dist_names:
    dist = getattr(st, dist_name)
    param = dist.fit(data)
    params[dist_name] = param

    # Applying the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test
    D_ks, p_ks = st.kstest(data, dist_name, args=param)
    print("Kolmogorov-Smirnov test Statistics value for " + dist_name + " = " + str(D_ks))
    print("p value (KS test) for " + dist_name + " = " + str(p_ks))
    dist_ks_results.append((dist_name, p_ks))

    # Applying the Anderson-Darling test:
    D_ad, p_ad = adnormtest(x=data, axis=0)
    print("Anderson-Darling test Statistics value for " + dist_name + " = " + str(D_ad))
    print("p value (AD test) for " + dist_name + " = " + str(p_ad))
    dist_ad_results.append((dist_name, p_ad))

# select the best fitted distribution:
best_ks_dist, best_ks_p = (max(dist_ks_results, key=lambda item: item[1]))
best_ad_dist, best_ad_p = (max(dist_ad_results, key=lambda item: item[1]))

print('\n################################ Kolmogorov-Smirnov test parameters #####################################')
print("Best fitting distribution (KS test) :" + str(best_ks_dist))
print("Best p value (KS test) :" + str(best_ks_p))
print("Parameters for the best fit (KS test) :" + str(params[best_ks_dist]))
print('###########################################################################################################\n')
print('################################ Anderson-Darling test parameters #########################################')
print("Best fitting distribution (AD test) :" + str(best_ad_dist))
print("Best p value (AD test) :" + str(best_ad_p))
print("Parameters for the best fit (AD test) :" + str(params[best_ad_dist]))
print('###########################################################################################################\n')
if best_ks_dist == best_ad_dist:
    best_common_dist = best_ks_dist
    print('##################################### Both test parameters ############################################')
    print("Best fitting distribution (Both test) :" + str(best_common_dist))
    print("Best p value (KS test) :" + str(best_ks_p))
    print("Best p value (AD test) :" + str(best_ad_p))
    print("Parameters for the best fit (Both test) :" + str(params[best_common_dist]))
    print('###########################################################################################################\n')
    return best_common_dist, best_ks_p, params[best_common_dist]
```

**Question 5:**

Correct me if I am wrong when implementing the Goodness-to-Fit test, the p-value obtained is used in order to check if the given values fit within any of the mentioned distributions. So, the maximum value of p-value means that the p-value lies below the %5 significant level of which, therefore, for example, Gamma distribution fits the data. Am I right or did I miss understood the main concept of the Goodness-to-Fit test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question 3 is easy to solve with [OpenTURNS](http://www.openturns.org/). I generally rank distributions with the Bayesian information criterion, because it allows to rank as being better the distributions which have fewer parameters.

In the following example, I create a gaussian distribution and generate a sample from it. Then I compute the BIC scores with the `FittingTest.BIC` function on the 30 distributions in the library. I then use the `np.argsort` function to get the sorted indices and print the results.

```
import openturns as ot
import numpy as np
# Generate a sample
distribution = ot.Normal()
sample = distribution.getSample(100)
tested_factories = ot.DistributionFactory.GetContinuousUniVariateFactories()
nbmax = len(tested_factories)
# Compute BIC scores
bic_scores = []
names = []
for i in range(nbmax):
    factory = tested_factories[i]
    names.append(factory.getImplementation().getClassName())
    try:
        fitted_dist, bic = ot.FittingTest.BIC(sample, factory)
    except:
        bic = np.inf
    bic_scores.append(bic)
# Sort the scores
indices = np.argsort(bic_scores)
# Print result
for i in range(nbmax):
    factory = tested_factories[i]
    name = factory.getImplementation().getClassName()
    print(names[indices[i]], ": ", i, bic_scores[indices[i]])
```

This produces:

```
NormalFactory :  0 2.902476153791324
TruncatedNormalFactory :  1 2.9391403094910493
LogisticFactory :  2 2.945101831314491
LogNormalFactory :  3 2.948479498106734
StudentFactory :  4 2.9487326727806438
WeibullMaxFactory :  5 2.9506160993704653
WeibullMinFactory :  6 2.9646030668970464
TriangularFactory :  7 2.9683050343363897
TrapezoidalFactory :  8 2.970676202179786
BetaFactory :  9 3.033244379700322
RayleighFactory :  10 3.0511170157342207
LaplaceFactory :  11 3.0641174552986796
FrechetFactory :  12 3.1472260896504327
UniformFactory :  13 3.1551588725784927
GumbelFactory :  14 3.1928562445001263
HistogramFactory :  15 3.3881831435932748
GammaFactory :  16 3.3925823197940552
ExponentialFactory :  17 3.824030948338899
ArcsineFactory :  18 214.7536151046246
ChiFactory :  19 680.8835152447839
ChiSquareFactory :  20 683.6769102883109
FisherSnedecorFactory :  21 inf
LogUniformFactory :  22 inf
GeneralizedParetoFactory :  23 inf
RiceFactory :  24 inf
DirichletFactory :  25 inf
BurrFactory :  26 inf
InverseNormalFactory :  27 inf
MeixnerDistributionFactory :  28 inf
ParetoFactory :  29 inf
```

There are distributions which cannot be fit on this sample. On these distributions, I set the BIC to INF and wrap the exception in a try/except.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will give it a try. I am just stuck with question 1, 2 and edit 1. Have you been through this situation?

Comment: Sorry, but I have no good idea on question 1... except that I would rather not do it personally.

Comment: Can you tell me the reason?

Comment: Also, is it common for some distributions to have same p-value? if it is what can I do in order to have unique values for each distribution?

Comment: Combining two methods to define a new one is not unusual. But the Kolmogorov-Test and the Anderson-Darling tests have different goals, so I cannot find a way to merge them. By the way, for the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test, your way of using the test is, I think, wrong : you should use the Lillifors test, as shown in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57354430/goodness-of-fit-test-for-weibull-distribution-in-python/59096874#59096874

Comment: I have a question, say that I used the scipy for the KS test and got the test statistics and p-value. Correct me if I am wrong when implementing the Goodness-to-Fit test, the p-value obtained is used in order to check if the given values fit within any of the mentioned distributions. So, the maximum value of p-value means that the p-value lies below the %5 significant level of which, therefore, for example, Gamma distribution fits the data. Am I right or did I miss understood the main concept of the Goodness-to-Fit test?

Answer (score 0):

The question 2. can be solved with the `NormalityTest.AndersonDarlingNormal` class:

```
import openturns as ot
distribution = ot.Normal()
sample = distribution.getSample(100)
test_result = ot.NormalityTest.AndersonDarlingNormal(sample)
print(test_result.getPValue())
```

This prints:

```
0.8267360272974381
```

The API is documented [in the help page of the function](http://openturns.github.io/openturns/master/user_manual/_generated/openturns.NormalityTest_AndersonDarlingNormal.html), there [is an example](http://openturns.github.io/openturns/master/examples/data_analysis/andersondarling_test.html) and [the theory is documented here](http://openturns.github.io/openturns/master/theory/data_analysis/anderson_darling_test.html).